# Redux - How to get updated input value on changing qty in handleChange

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I fetched data and show the cart information of user,

Now i want to change the quantity of product from input field.

But when i change the quantity, it always get that value **(see in handleChange)** which stored in database.

Bydefault value is 1, but i if change to 2 **(from input value)**, it should go 2 in **const qty** in handleChange function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { cartItems, removeCart, updateCart } from '../actions/cartAction';

class Cart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let getValue = localStorage.getItem("userData");     
    this.setState({ 
      getValue: JSON.parse(getValue), 
    }); 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const emailData = this.state.getValue.email;
    this.props.cartItems(emailData);
  }

  handleChange = (share) => (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    const cID = share._id;
    const pprice = share.pprice;
    const qty = share.qty;
    const updateData = {cID: cID, pprice: pprice, qty: qty}
    this.props.updateCart(updateData);
  };

  render() {
      return (
          <tbody>
            {this.props.cartDetails.length && this.props.cartDetails.map(share => {
             return ( 
              <tr key={share._id}>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <p> {share.pid} </p>
                </td>
                <th class="text-center" scope="row">
                   <img src="assets/img/product/2.jpg" alt="img" height="150px"/>
                </th>
                <td class="text-center">
                   <span class="whish-title">{share.pname}</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <span class="whish-list-price">
                   {share.pprice}
                  </span>
                </td>                                            
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="product-count style">
                    <div class="count d-flex justify-content-center">
                      <input type="number" onChange={this.handleChange(share)} defaultValue={share.qty} name="qty" min="1" max="10" step="1"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                 <span class="whish-list-price">
                  {share.total_price}
                 </span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <span class="whish-list-price">
                    <button onClick={this.deleteCart(share)} className="btn theme-btn--dark1 btn--md">Delete</button>
                  </span>
                </td>
               </tr>   
             );
            })}  
          </tbody>   
      ) 
    }
 }    

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ cartDetails: state.cartDetails });

const mapDispatchToProps = {cartItems, removeCart, updateCart};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is on

```
    const updateData = {cID: cID, pprice: pprice, qty: qty}
```

Why you use `share.qty` instead of `event.target.value`?
I also don't understand the sense of

```
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
```

Where do you use these values?

Comment: use event.target.value instead of share.qty, Did the trick, thank you